# QGIS Raster Merge, Projection Error

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, gdal-merge

I am trying to merge a collection of NED10m tiles using QGIS and the GDAL>Raster miscellaneous>Merge command.  The command executes but my output raster has a projections issue.  Below are two screen grabs from my work. The first has the original tiles. The second has the merged DEM layer and the upper left tile for reference.  Does anyone else have this issue? If so do you know of an easy workaround using QGIS or another open-source solution?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you made sure you used the correct CRS for source and target layer?

Comment: Yes, I am working in NAD83 UTM 10.  All the tiles are from the same source so I should be constant for all the tiles.

Comment: Looking closer, this data is on the border of California and Nevada to I am half in UTM 10 and Half in UTM 11

Comment: Yes, that was the issue.  Half of my data will need to be re-projected. I found a video link that was helpful in making the process smooth. Thanks Erik. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6--NY6P56g

Comment: Post this as an answer and accept it.